# Insert data take long query time

Tags: sql

I have following structure need to loop over and INSERT to corresponding table.However I have experience horrible long time to process the query until connection close by server.
I need a faster way to process the query.Please advice.thanks
Noted that I use ms sql server

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry myInfo in myOrderInfo){//contain 183 times

foreach (DictionaryEntry myBi in myInfo.value){//loop 13 times
...//some code
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + myBi.Key, myBi.Value + "");
....
connection2.open()
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection2.close();

}
.....//some conditions

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + myInfo.Key, myInfo.Value + "");
.....//some conditions

connection.open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reuse the connection.

Put the open and close connection methods outside of the for loops.

This will speed it up a lot.

Quick edit: You don't really need to use two connections either if you are going to the same database server. Something like this should be your end result.

```
        connection.open();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry myInfo in myOrderInfo){//contain 183 times

        foreach (DictionaryEntry myBi in myInfo.value){//loop 13 times
        ...//some code
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + myBi.Key, myBi.Value + "");
        ....
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        .....//some conditions

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + myInfo.Key, myInfo.Value + "");
        .....//some conditions

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.close();
```

Comment: Thx,Alex your solution has significant improvement.
It takes 4 minutes to process.
Is it posible to make the whole process faster than 4 minute.

Actually,the query above process only 1 day of data,when it comes to live environment,it might need to process up to 7 days' data.

Comment: Its much more better than before,at lease connection not timesout at the moment.

May I to query multiple INSERT and execute one-off.Does it improve the processing time?